# Default to MyISAM instead of InnoDB in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, database

Can I make Drupal default to MyISAM for new tables instead of InnoDB? Except for hacking the core, that is.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest and dirtiest way to get all Drupal data into MyISAM perform the following:

Make a backup of /var/lib/mysql before doing these steps

step 1. mysqldump all data out of mysql

step 2. remove all folders and files from /var/lib/mysql, but leave the `/var/lib/mysql/mysql` alone because it contains user grants.

step 3. add this line in /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
skip-innodb
```

step 4. `service mysql restart`

step 5. reload mysqldump file back into data into mysql database

**UPDATE 2011-10-04 04:28 EDT**

step 1. [**Set Default Storage Engine to MyISAM**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-storage-engine)

add this line in /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine = MyISAM
```

step 2. `service mysql restart`

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it disabled InnoDB for everyone, and I'm interested in disabling it for a single database / site.

Comment: Updated my answer to set storage engine default only !!!

Comment: A very significant caveat: D7 is built with the assumption that transactions exist. IMO you can't expect Drupal 7 to behave predictably with s non-trsnsactional engine like MyIsam.